# How to insert data between mysql fetched result in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a new predefined data after 6th line while fetching result from mysql in php. After that, I want to insert a predefined text after every 5th line.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

if((($i%6)== 0)&&($i!=0))
{

$emparray['category'] = "PREDEFINED DATA";
array_push($json_response,$emparray);

}

//Data from the database
$emparray['category'] = ucwords($row["tag"]);
array_push($json_response,$emparray);
++$i;
}
```

This is my code that I had managed but it gives me "PREDEFINED DATA" after every 6th line. What I want is that after 6th line message should be shown after every 5th line.

Comment: have you tried `$i % 5 == 0` instead of `$i % $6` ?

Comment: @EmmanuelO Sorry for the mistake it is not $6 it is 6 and yes I had tried 5 too but after first 6 line I want the message after every 5th line. int 5 too doesn't give me the desired output.

Comment: Try `$i % 5 == 1 && $i`.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: So you want "separator" as line 7 (after 6 rows), 13 (after next 5),19 (after next 5), 25... and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `value` of `key` `['category']` of the associative array `$emparray` to be assigned as `predefined data` **instead** of the fetched result `$row['tag']` at the 6th, 11th, 17th place and so on, the below code would give you the desired result.

```
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   if(($i%6)==0){
     $emparray['category'] = "PREDEFINED DATA";
   }
   else{
//Data from the database
     $emparray['category'] = ucwords($row["tag"]);
   }
   array_push($json_response,$emparray);
   $i++;
}
```

---

If you want to add `predefined data` to the 6th, 11th, 17th place, and **push** the 6th fetched result `$row['tag']` to the 7th place, you should do it like this.

```
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   if(($i%6)==0){
     $emparray['category'] = "PREDEFINED DATA";
     array_push($json_response,$emparray);
     $i++;
   }
//Data from the database
     $emparray['category'] = ucwords($row["tag"]);
     array_push($json_response,$emparray);
     $i++;
}
```

If you want `predefined data` to be added at the 6th, 11th, 17th place, **in addition** to the 6th, 11th, 17th value of the fetched result `$row["tag"]`, you are approaching this wrongly as you can't assign two values to a key, you would need to make `$emparray['category']` a subarray i.e. `$emparray['category'][]` instead or concatenate the two before assigning it to the key.

Comment: Can't believe how can I do this type of mistake.
Thanks. :)

Comment: @JackStern Glad to be of help, so what you wanted was to add them to a sub-array?

Answer (score 1):

Please set value of `$i = 1` before loop. And `$i % 5 == 0` in if condition.

```
$i = 1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

if((($i%5)== 0)&&($i!=0))
{

$emparray['category'] = "PREDEFINED DATA";
array_push($json_response,$emparray);

}

//Data from the database
$emparray['category'] = ucwords($row["tag"]);
array_push($json_response,$emparray);
++$i;
}
```

Comment: First time will be triggered after fourth row. May be `$i = -1`?